# bash/readline for "move forward by whitespace-delimited word?"

Tags: bash, readline

In bash/readline, if you want to navigate through a command, often you have things like:

```
cat /home/foo/bar.txt /home/bar/baz.txt
```

If my cursor is at the end of the line (^e), and I want to move back to the start of the second argument, how do I move to the (next/previous) whitespace?

Readline has built-in `Meta-f` (forward) and `Meta-b` (backwards), but these will stop at the slashes in the paths, not move all the way to the whitespace.

vim has `W` and `B` which will do this, but vim movement mode is not enabled in readline/bash by default.

Comment: If you are familiar with `vi`, why not switching (and staying) in `vi` mode?

Answer (score 13):

You can use vim movement commands in readline/bash even while still in emacs movement mode.  The relevant readline commands are `vi-fWord` and `vi-bWord`.  You can bind them to keyboard shortcuts such as `CTRL-f` and `CTRL-b` with the following in your `.bash_profile`:

```
bind '"\C-f":vi-fWord'
bind '"\C-b":vi-bWord'
```

Note that the double quoting is significant.

You can confirm that the bindings are working by running `bind -p`

Comment: As I like having my readline configuration reside completely within ~/.inputrc , you can drop the *bind* and surrounding single quotes and add it directly to ~/.inputrc

Comment: In case it helps anyone else you can get this working in fish shell by adding `bind \cb backward-bigword` and `bind \cf forward-bigword` to your `~\.config\config.fish`

Answer (score 7):

There are Readline commands that let you move and treat words like the shell treats them for splitting: `shell-forward-word` and `shell-backward-word`<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to bind them to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to avoid overwriting the existing bindings, you can use

```
bind '"\M-\C-f": shell-forward-word'
bind '"\M-\C-b": shell-backward-word'
```

on the command line, or add

```
"\M-\C-f": shell-forward-word
"\M-\C-b": shell-backward-word
```

to the relevant `inputrc` file (usually `~/.inputrc`).

Depending on the setting of `convert-meta`, `\M-` has to be replaced with `\e`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Introduced in Bash 4.0.

Comment: Good stuff! Note that this feature was introduced in bash 4.0 so it's not working on the stock Mac OS Bash version.